# Why did this query which worked in MySQL4 not work in MySQL5?

Tags: mysql

Recently upgraded a database from MySQL 4 to MySQL 5. The following query is now broken:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer, Product INNER JOIN Orders 
ON (Customer.Email = Orders.Email)
WHERE NOT (Product.Flags & 8) AND 
    Customer.CustomerNumber = Product.CustomerNumber AND
    Truncate(Orders.ProductId/10, 0) = Truncate(Product.ProductId/10, 0)
```

Getting the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'Customer.Email' in 'on clause'
```

I didn't write this query, and I am not a SQL guru, but I'm am guessing is may be a mix of ANSI-89/ANSI-92 style joins and there may be some kind of precedence issue going on.

Can you explain the error, describing what's wrong with this query, and how to correctly specify the joins?

Comment: Obvious question, there is, in fact a column named 'Email' on the Customer table, right?

Comment: Mark, I think you'll have better luck at [`dba.stackexchange.com`](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Are you sure this worked previously? You're combining ANSI and non-ANSI joins here...

Comment: This is a programming not an administration question @BurhanKhalid. There's absolutely no need for this to be moved. It is on topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have you tried changing the first join (the comma) to "INNER JOIN" (you'll need to add an ON clause). On the DB2/400 RDBMS, I know that mixing sometimes did not work.

Comment: @aktrazer: Yes, the field exists.  Ben: This query has been in place for many years, and the system functioned properly.  I can poke the query into myPHPAdmin on the version 4 database and it does not any errors and gives us an expected result. But in MySql 5, it chokes. Darius No I haven't tried that yet, I need to pull out a SQL book and learn a little more since I'm mostly family with the older SQL styles that I learned 20 years ago. Back to being a student all over again.  ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented under [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html):

> #### Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The following list provides more detail about several effects of current join processing versus join processing in older versions. The term “previously” means “prior to MySQL 5.0.12.”
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - Previously, the comma operator (`,`) and `JOIN` both had the same precedence, so the join expression `t1, t2 JOIN t3` was interpreted as `((t1, t2) JOIN t3)`. Now `JOIN` has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`. This change affects statements that use an `ON` clause, because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes interpretation of what those operands are.
>
>   Example:
>
>   ```
>   CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT, j1 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT, j2 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT, j3 INT);
>   INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t3 VALUES(1,1);
>   SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Previously, the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) was legal due to the implicit grouping of `t1,t2` as `(t1,t2)`. Now the `JOIN` takes precedence, so the operands for the `ON` clause are `t2` and `t3`. Because `t1.i1` is not a column in either of the operands, the result is an `Unknown column 't1.i1' in 'on clause'` error. To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the `ON` clause are `(t1,t2)` and `t3`:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Alternatively, avoid the use of the comma operator and use `JOIN` instead:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   This change also applies to statements that mix the comma operator with `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and `RIGHT JOIN`, all of which now have higher precedence than the comma operator.

Comment: Thanks much for this detailed answer. It makes sense, and a simple set of parenthesis restores the query to its proper functioning again. Though I now realize from looking for answers online that I probably want to get rid of that comma join altogether and replace it with another inner join. (?)

Comment: @MarkS: Yes, the explicit join syntax introduced in SQL-92 solves a number of problems that arose with the implicit join syntax.  It's generally considered good practice to avoid implicit joins now, although I still find that they can occasionally be useful when one genuinely does want a `CROSS JOIN`.